# Best practice for storing user history in DB

Tags: database, android-activity, logging

I need some advice...
I have an application where users can do certain actions.
For example, users can have friends.
So...
Users can see his friends activity.
So how should I implement the activity log in the DB?
Should I have a new table?
Can I do some queries from multiple table and sort a joined result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you create an activity_type table and a logs table.

```
activity_type | id | name           | table
--------------+----+----------------+-------
                 1 | added friend   | tbl_users
                 2 | added comment  | tbl_comments
                 3 | added image    | tbl_images
                 4 | Updated dp     | NULL
```

Now you can easily maintain logs using the following table

```
   logs_table | id | user | activity_type  | object_id | time_stamp
--------------+----+------+----------------+-----------+------------
                 1 | 15   | 1              | 5         | 2012-03-10 08:45:05
                 2 | 15   | 2              | 19        | 2012-03-10 08:46:05
                 3 | 15   | 3              | 84        | 2012-03-10 08:47:05
                 4 | 15   | 4              | NULL      | 2012-03-10 08:48:05
```

User#15 added a new friend user#5 on 10th March.

User#15 added a new comment#19 on 10th March.

User#15 added a new image#84 on 10th March.

User#15 changed his display picture on 10th March.

**UPDATE**
There may be activities where object_id doesn't make sense like- updated display image, updated profile info etc. Here you can possibly store diff of text in a separate column.

The same approach can be used for storing audit logs.